# Replace Entire Comment Box with Text

Tags: comments, comment-form

I have a need to disable comments for a specific group of users. But I want to replace the entire comment box with a message like "Sorry, you are not allowed to enter a comment".

Other users should still be able to enter a comment in the normal way.

I don't think I found a filter to do that, but I may be looking in the wrong area of comments.php.

Is there a way to replace the entire comment area with a message?

**Added**

This ability is being added to a plugin, so it needs to be theme-independent - effective on all sites where the plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be pretty universally functional across themes, as long as they use something like the normal comment form code.

```
if ( ! current_user_can( $capability_required_for_commenting ) ) { 
    add_filter('comments_open', 'disable_comments', 20, 2);
    add_action('comment_form_comments_closed', 'display_no_comment_permissions_message' );
}
```

And then somewhere you'll want to define:

```
function disable_comments() {
    return false;
}

function display_no_comment_permissions_message() { ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but you aren’t able to comment!', 'text-domain' ); ?></p>
<?php }
```

Probably the place you want to add this is somewhere around the call to `comment_form()`.

Comment: Your solution would be effective, except my needs is more global, and not theme-dependent, as it is a function of a plugin I am writing. I updated the question with that info. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok. You could hide the comment form with CSS (target #respond) and hook your message into the `comment_form_before` action — that ought to work OK, although maybe there's a better solution than CSS here.

Comment: Got it — updated the answer.

Comment: This looks really good - and is simple to implement with an 'if' statement to add the actions. It might even be more simplified with a add_filter('function_name', function code.....) thing. But exactly what I was looking for.